# Getting an object from _.pluck with lo-dash/underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an object structured like this:

```
var my_object = {
  first_item: {important_number: 4},
  second_item: {important_number: 6},
}
```

However, I would like an object structured like this:

```
{
  first_item: 4,
  second_item: 6,
}
```

I would have expected to be able to get this result with `_.pluck`:

```
_.pluck(my_object, "important_number")
```

But this gives me:

```
[0: 4, 1: 6]
```

Good, but I need the actual names of the objects. I fiddled around and ended up with this:

```
_.reduce(my_object, function(memo, val, key) {
  memo[key] = val.content;
  return memo;
}, {});
```

Which has the desired effect, but isn't as simple as I would like. Is there a better solution in underscore/lodash, or is this the best it will get?

Comment: Since all underscore enumerators return arrays, this is the best you will get (though you could something shorter but less efficient like `zip(keys(obj), pluck(values(obj), "content"))`).

Comment: I just set up a JSPerf test for the 2, and in my browser your option is 2% faster!
http://jsperf.com/getting-an-object-from-pluck

Comment: However, yours gives this: `[["first_item", 4], ["second_item", 6]]` rather than the expected `{first_item: 4, second_item: 6}`

Comment: Ooops, I meant `_.object` (which zips key-and-value lists to an object) instead of `_.zip`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Lo-Dash you could also use [_.transform](http://lodash.com/docs#transform), a more powerful alternative to [_.reduce](http://lodash.com/docs#reduce):

```
_.transform(my_object, function(memo, val, key) {
  memo[key] = val.important_number;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually what you're describing - that is "`pluck` for object values" - can be written as:

```
_.mapValues(my_object, "important_number")
```

See documentation of [`_.mapValues`](http://lodash.com/docs#mapValues).

[`_.createCallback`](http://lodash.com/docs#createCallback) - which does the string to property magic - is used all over the place in Lo-Dash: search for `"_.pluck" style callback`.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's fun to use Lo-Dash/Underscore, but if you have to use 2 functions instead of just using a regular loop, you're better off using 'old_school' coding style:

```
var data = {
  first_item: {important_number: 4},
  second_item: {important_number: 6},
};

var obj = {};

for (var i in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) obj[i] = data[i].important_number;  
}
```

Just to prove my point, I updated your JsPerf to include the regular for loop, and watch the magic: http://jsperf.com/getting-an-object-from-pluck/2

**Regular For Loop** is at least **2x** faster than any other method you guys posted here. And that's mainly because it only traverses the object once.

Comment: Hi, maintainer of jsPerf and Lo-Dash here ;D.
Your jsPerf isn't magic, it's simply faster because it's got less abstraction, but that's nothing new. The methods posted above only iterate the object once, however they incur the cost of executing a callback and are more generic than your targeted snippet. The OP was looking for a simpler option using lib sugar not unrolling it to bare metal JS.

Comment: I didn't know about `_.transform` - great to know about it (I use underscore.js mainly). Anyway if you have a 1 function solution to the poster question, that's what he wanted

Comment: Here's the 1 function solution: `_.mapValues(my_object, "important_number")`

Comment: Is not necessary faster: the writing and maintenance of such "regular for" can take you up to some minute per year vs some millisecond per run of gain; if the code runs in outer loops, you have to run that code roughly 10^5 times in a year to justify the time the dev losts because of "optimization". Humans are the slowest devices + Amdahl's law = the computer latency may be widely negligible.